# Background push notifications arrive when code is executed via XCode but not if running independently of XCode

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm observing a strange situation with background push notifications. (Note I mean the new iOS7 background push, I am not talking about regular pushes when the app is in the background).

If I run my app using XCode and send it to the background and send it some background push notifications then they are *all* received (and almost instantly).

But then if I run the app by starting it manually from the device and send it some more pushes *none* of them are received when the app is in the background (but it receives them if the app is in the foreground).

This is 100% repeatable - I can switch back to running via XCode and all pushes are received in the background. Switch back to running manually and none are received in the background.

Anybody any idea what's going on?

(I'm checking if they are arriving or not by observing NSLog output to Organizer's console).

Comment: I don't see the relevance of the link? My app is implementing didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler as is supposed to instead of didReceiveRemoteNotification: when dealing with background pushes.

Comment: @Rich, the Apple documentation says regarding didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler "Implement this method if your app supports the remote-notification background mode". application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: does NOT get called if the app is in the background (unless the user interacts with a notification in notifiation manager). Where does piepants say he is dealing with foreground notifications? His problem is he is not receiving  a background notification.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT: Problem seems to be an Apple regression bug, see comments.

Not an answer as to why but my comments are too large to go in the comments section.

Firstly I've noticed that the background behavior of apps is different when you run them via Xcode, so if you are developing and testing any sort of background behavior DON'T rely just on testing running via Xcode. Make sure you run the apps manually as you are doing as there is a difference in behavior.

Secondly I've seen something similar to yourself - which is that turning wifi on/off is having an effect on my apps ability to receive background pushes:

1) have app running in background with wifi off and send a push, chances are the app doesn't get it

2) have app running in background with wifi on and send a push, the app will get it

3) have app running in foreground and turn wifi off and send a push, the app will get it.

I don't see why 1) should be causing a problem - if wifi is off the push can still get through to the app as evidenced by 3). As to why wifi on/off is having an effect on the push not being delivered to the app when the app is in the background I have no idea and suspect it could be an Apple bug?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Like I said "Not an answer as to why but my comments are too large to go in the comments section". I clearly say its not an answer and I clearly state my comments are too large to go in the comments section. You obviously have a problem with inflexibility?

Comment: None the less, it is not an answer and should be deleted.

Comment: @Martin H. Useful info, thanks.

Comment: Because it is the rules.  Stack Overflow is not a forum, it is a question-answer site.  Answers should answer the question.  Feel free to bring this up on [meta] if you want to discuss this further.

Comment: I have multiple devices and have noticed that a device that is working properly has iOS 7.0.4 on it, while one that doesn't has 7.1 on it. I'm currently updating the one with 7.1 to 7.1.1 to see if the issue gets fixed after the update.

Comment: Wifi is the reason!! If I had Wifi turned off I was getting this problem, but after turning it on its now ok. I too have 7.1

Comment: 7.1.1 doesn't fix it. Tried it on a few other devices and its ok with earlier software but not with the latest. It must be an Apple bug that was introduced between 7.04 onwards